# Group By Having clearification

Tags: mysql

This is what im trying to acheieve (written in imaginery sql):

```
SELECT A, B, C, AVG(  `Value` ) AS Value
FROM T 
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING AT LEAST TWO DIFFRENT C VALUES PER DISTINCT A,B 
ORDER BY A, B, C
```

Is it possible to rewrite such HAVING condition in proper mysql?

At First i thought this would work :

```
    SELECT A, B, C, AVG(  `Value` ) AS Value
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY A, B, C
    HAVING COUNT(C)>2
    ORDER BY A, B, C
```

But it doesnt since its not possible 2 diffrent C value for the same A, B, C combination, so how would you do it?

Comment: Please show example in- and output data.

Comment: But if you want “different C’s”, then you probably don’t want to include C in your grouping in the first place - _because_ grouping by A, B, C means `1, 2, X` and `1, 2, Y` would be _different_ groups to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide your query into two different queries:

1. Having at least two different C values per distinct A,B

   ```
   select A, B
   from T
   group by A, B
   having count(DISTINCT C)>1
   ```
2. your final query

   ```
   select  A, B, C, avg(Value)
   from T
   where
     (A, B) in (
       select A, B
       from T
       group by A, B
       having count(DISTINCT C)>1
     )
   group by
     A, B, C
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use *WHERE* statement instead of *HAVING*

```
SELECT A, B, C, AVG(  `Value` ) AS Value
FROM T 
WHERE 
     (
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C)
     FROM T1
     WHERE T1.A = T.A AND T1.B = T.B
     ) >= 2
GROUP BY A, B, C
ORDER BY A, B, C
```